# How to import the Android ROM source code into Android Studio?

Tags: android, c, android-studio, rom

I have downloaded one `Android ROM source code`, it has many file and folder, which takes a lot disk space (about 40GB). If I want to use android studio to edit some file, for example, `/$ROM/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/DataSource.cpp`

Because, while editing the `.cpp file`, I want the android studio IDE can point out where the wrong code is, and provide the function library. Just like editing normal android project java file.

How to import the `ROM source code into` Android Studio??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are Google docs to describe how you do it :

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Go for "Create a New Project with C/C++ Support" step directly if you do not like to have a native build in it.